# Facebook uses http instead of https for redirect after login

Tags: reactjs, spring, facebook, nginx, oauth

I have a Spring app and a React act written so that the user can use facebook to login. I have also bought a domain with an SSL certificate and installed the certificate in my nginx reverse proxy.

Here is my nginx config (it runs in a docker container):

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}



http {

    server { 
        listen          80;
        server_name     frontend;
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;
            
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000/;
        }
    
    }
    
    server { 
        listen                  443 ssl;
        server_name             frontend_secure;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/private/8e3a263352b3f661.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.key;
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;
            
            proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:3000;
        }
        
        location /api {
            proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;
            
            proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:8081;
        }
    
    }
}
```

I added my https domain to the App Domains, Site URL, Domains and Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in the Facebook console. In the backend spring config I have my https domain setup as the login success url:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/login**", "/callback/", "/webjars/**", "/error**", "/api/users/availableAuths").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth_login", "/loginFailure", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("https://domain.dev/", true)
                .failureUrl("/loginFailure")
                .loginPage("/api/users/availableAuths")
                .and()
                .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/");
```

I can see the frontend properly (with secure https) and it redirects to facebook correctly to login. The problem is that when I login I get this message:

```
Facebook has detected Eat App isn't using a secure connection to transfer information.
Until Eat App updates its security settings, you won't be able to use Facebook to log into it.
```

I can see that in the link where facebook stops there is

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth? (...) redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.dev%2Fapi%2Flogin%2Foauth2%2Fcode%2Ffacebook
```

So the `redirect_uri` in the facebook url is HTTP and not HTTPS. Why is that? Where does this `redirect_uri` param with http come from?